# Is my GLM model with a binomial distribution correctly implemented?

Tags: r, glm, effects

I've been trying to implement a GLM model using data on the success of a genetic test (yes= successful test; no= unsuccesful test).

```
> head(dataraw)
   success     pre during season observer
1:      no pre-wet    dry winter   JvD&OK
2:     yes pre-wet    dry winter   JvD&OK
3:      no pre-wet    dry winter   JvD&OK
4:     yes pre-wet    dry winter      JvD
5:     yes pre-wet    dry winter      JvD
6:     yes pre-wet    dry winter      JvD
```

Four predictor variables are used to explain the ocurrence of the response variable `success`, being `pre` (`pre-wet` or `pre-dry`), `during` (`wet` or `dry`),`season` (`winter` or `fall`) and `observer` (up to 10 different observers).

I would like to find which variables are the most important in explaining a succesful test, i.e. `success`:`yes`.

I've constructed the models following the code below with and without interactions between the different effects, and have chosen the most parsimonious model following a theoretical approach with AIC values:

```
m1 <- glm((success) ~ pre , data=dataraw , family=binomial)
summary(m1)
plot(allEffects(m1))
AIC(m1)

m2 <- glm((success) ~ during , data=dataraw , family=binomial)
summary(m2)
plot(allEffects(m2))
AIC(m2)

m3 <- glm((success) ~ season , data=dataraw , family=binomial)
summary(m3)
plot(allEffects(m3))
AIC(m3)

m4 <- glm((success) ~ observer , data=dataraw , family=binomial)
summary(m4)
plot(allEffects(m4))
AIC(m4)

m5 <- glm((success) ~ pre*during , data=dataraw , family=binomial)
summary(m4)
plot(allEffects(m4))
AIC(m4)

etc.
```

I'm unsure whether I'm following the good approach and if my code is correct, specially since I've seen other people use `1` (for yes) and `0` (for no) when using a binomial distribution. Does that matter? Is my dataset `dataraw` implemented correctly?

Hope somebody can set me on the right track and I hope this question can be of interest.

Comment: I don't think it matters how you state your binary dependent variable as long as it is binary. The best way to go about this would be to attempt to get the best AIC value but also think about the problem itself to see which is the most applicable. An example would be a very complex processing problem in a manufacturing plant. You could have some significant values, and a lower AIC with certain variables, but it would be impossible to implement those into practice. If this problem is purely theoretical then just go with the lowest AIC model.

Answer (score 1):

You may convert the `success` column to factor. So if you execute other models like xgboost you won't get any error

```
    dataraw$success = as.factor(dataraw$success)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting it as 0,1 and no,yes gives the same results. To orient your coefficients correctly, you need to makes sure the class you are trying to predict is encoded as 1, or is 2nd in the levels.

See below for an example:

```
df <- mtcars
# setting it as 1 and 0
# creating a response based on mpg values
df$response <- ifelse(df$mpg > 20,1,0)
coefficients(summary(glm(response ~ gear,data=df,family="binomial")))

             Estimate Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -4.487170  2.1205286 -2.116062 0.03433955
gear         1.143544  0.5630026  2.031152 0.04223960

df$response <- factor(ifelse(df$mpg > 20,"yes","no"))
# setting it as a factor
#by default,levels are sorted alphabetically, so it works if it is yes/no
levels(df$response)
[1] "no"  "yes"
coefficients(summary(glm(response ~ gear,data=df,family="binomial")))

             Estimate Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -4.487170  2.1205286 -2.116062 0.03433955
gear         1.143544  0.5630026  2.031152 0.04223960

# now we flip the levels
# you can see coefficients are flipped
df$response <- factor(ifelse(df$mpg > 20,"yes","no"),levels=c("yes","no"))
coefficients(summary(glm(response ~ gear,data=df,family="binomial")))

             Estimate Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  4.487170  2.1205286  2.116062 0.03433955
gear        -1.143544  0.5630026 -2.031152 0.04223960
```

As for finding "which variables are the most important in explaining a succesful test", I would try a full model as well:

```
glm(success ~ . + pre:during, data=dataraw , family=binomial)
```

In case some variables are correlated, you will see that it might give different results from evaluating each on its own